# Can I get notified when a specific user makes a new post?

Tags: feature-request

Suppose I work/learn on/about a specific subject, let's say JPA, after making searches and asking questions on SO, I've noticed that some person is very good at JPA and it would be very interesting to be notified about his posts. Is it possible to be told about their new activities on SO?

I think that it would be interesting to have this feature in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature already exists.

If you go to a user's ['Activity' tab](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/33591/mithrandir?tab=topactivity), you'll see that all the way at the bottom, under the votes, there's a user feed link:

[image]

This will give you an [RSS feed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/33591) for all contributions by that user, including answers and comments.

I will caution you, however, that this feature is not meant to be used for you to upvote all posts by a user. Vote for the post, not for the person; voting based on who posted it considered abusive behavior and you could be suspended for it. So be careful - don't use this to upvote all new posts by one specific user.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I actually tried what you suggested and I did find the contributions of the person, but this RSS is kinda unreadable.

Comment: You can set up as a feed somewhere - say, Feedly - and then you can have an actual feed, and that eliminates the 'unreadable' problem.